# How to get only unique nodes from a collection - IEnumerable<XNode>

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-xml

I'm querying a XML column in a SQL database from code behind in C#. I'm trying to get a list of only unique nodes.

In the table, there's many ItemCodes(PK) each with a corresponding `ItemAttribute` which is the XML type column.

Say there's 10 rows and 3 nodes in the XML document. I get 30 results from the method I use below. I only want unique nodes returned, but because there's unique data in each node, I get any number of results returned depending on the uniqueness of a value in a node.

```
var data = (from x in Ctx.ItemAttributeDatas 
            select x).ToList();

var xml = from x in data
          where x.AttributeData.Descendants() != null
          select x.AttributeData as XElement;

IEnumerable<XNode> nodes = (from x in xml.Nodes()
                            select x);
```

How can this be done? I tried using `.Distinct()` but problem as above had same results.

Also, is there a cleaner way I can get the data to xml to nodes?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `EqualityComparer` for `XNode`

```
IEnumerable<XNode> nodes = (from x in xml.Nodes()
                        select x).Distinct(XNode.EqualityComparer);
```

Comment: Tried that, but still same result. If there's only three nodes in the XML schema (e.g A, B, C) I only want those three nodes returned. What's happening is because there may be different values associated with a node in each row in table, A might get returned 5 times because there's a different value associated with A in each row.

Comment: Your answer works for the data in each node. I want unique nodes/tags returned. Any other ideas?